# Unable to remove jquery from header and put in before body ends

Tags: jquery

For [wordpress blog](http://staging12.blog.grabon.in/), even after removing `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` from theme function jquery is getting loaded, so I have two query:

1. From where jquery is getting loaded
2. How to move default jquery to footer before body tag ends

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is built into WordPress, so if any other enqueued script relies on it, it's automatically loaded.

To move it to the footer, you have to reregister it, like this:

```
function my_footer_jquery () {
    wp_deregister_script ('jquery');
    wp_register_script ('jquery', includes_url ('/js/jquery/jquery.js'), array (), NULL, true);
    wp_enqueue_script ('jquery');
}
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_footer_jquery');
```

Comment: I tried doing this, ideally while registering script if last argument is `true` it should come in footer but for my blog it is coming in head only, not able to figure out the exact reason behind this